# Can you check what the upgrade on a type of card will be in-game?

Tags: clash-royale

Now you can see what the upgrade will be once you have collected all cards of that type you need in order to buy the upgrade. Is there an in-game way to see what the upgrade will be, so you can choose which type of cards to request / keep?

I know you can check the [Clash Royale Wikia](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clash_Royale_Wikia), but in-game would save browsing, searching and checking your current level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can. It's qutie simple actually:
**An upgrade adds +10% to the stats.**

```
For troops:
+10% Hit-points
+10% Damage
+10% Damage per Second 

For Buildings its:
+10% Hit-points
+1 Troop level/ +10% Damage

For Spells its:
+10% Damage
(for freeze +0.3s duration)
```

Comment: This rule applied for the cards I've checked on Wikia. Thanks!

Comment: Spells upgrade with fixed amounts of seconds each upgrade. In case of freeze 0.3 seconds for each upgrade.